# Google maps causes invisible html elements only on iPad, strange behaviour why?

Tags: javascript, ipad, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

If you have an iPad go check this page out [www.toughtomato.com/view](http://www.toughtomato.com/view) on your iPad (I tested this on iPad2). Now check it on your desktop browser - any browser doesn't matter.

If you noticed the menu on the left disappears on the iPad, the elements are still there though because you can tap to click them.

Now I have pinned this behaviour down to the inclusion of the Google Maps v3 script on the page:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false'></script>
```

If I remove this single line of code from the HTML on this page then the menu remains visible on iPad. What could be causing this and is there a solution?

Thanks for any help. This is a very frustrating problem!

**[EDIT] I've removed all JS from the page apart from the Google Maps script.**

Comment: Your new url doesn't have a map. It is the case that your previous URL does do something odd: all the test goes blurry as well once the map is scrolled into view.

Comment: It does have a map, right at the bottom of contact page. I have a work around for the issue now, and that is to create the map in a totally separate page and then pull it in with an iframe.

Comment: Your link doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You can generalise this problem as: I am including 3rd party JavaScript on my page and when I do it changes the presentation and/or behaviour of what was there without the 3rd party JavaScript.

Whether the Google Maps JS inclusion is causing the matter is not really possible to say.

It could be that the Google Maps JS is modifying the DOM which impacts your presentation. It could be that the Google Maps JS is conflicting with your JS. This could be due to poorly-written Google Maps JS. This could be due to your JS being poorly written.

There are too many factors to suggest a solution or even a single starting point.

You can try:

- removing your JS and see if the problem persists; if not, investigate in what way the affected content of your page is dependent on your JS and how your JS could be rewritten to not conflict with the Google Maps JS
- examining the DOM with and without JS enabled and see in what ways the Google Maps JS could be modifying things
- examining the applied styles on the affected content; how could your CSS be updated to compensate?

Comment: thanks for your suggestions. I have removed all JS from the page apart from the Google Maps script. I have also checked the CSS styles on the iPad by launching Firebug light (tut http://martinkool.com/post/13629963755/firebug-on-ipad-and-iphone) - both show no difference, I will try to disable JS and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate that you found a work-around solution sometime ago by embedding the map using an iFrame, however, I resolved this problem by adding the following property to the invisible elements.

```
z-index: -1;
```

The elements only became invisible after the Google Maps JS had loaded, so clearly it was manipulating the DOM. Unfortunately, the block level elements it targeted had no commonalities, but they where the first and last block elements within the body tag. Curious.

Anyway, I hope this solution helps someone who chances upon this odd bug.

PS. I was testing my site on an iPad 1 running iOS 5.1.1

Comment: Hi Simon, I am running into this frustrating bug too. I am not totally sure what elements I should be trying to add the z-index to though?

Answer (score 1):

Thought i would chip in on this too. After playing around with z-indexs and getting no where I found this post

[iPad Safari scrolling causes HTML elements to disappear and reappear with a delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807620/ipad-safari-scrolling-causes-html-elements-to-disappear-and-reappear-with-a-dela)

Which was to do with elements being hidden during scroll.

One of the fixes was to use

```
*:not(html) {
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
```

To force hardware acceleration (I think). I used modified version (applying it to all divs) and behold it works.

Hope this is helpful to someone else.