# Ipad with Retina Display UIWebView does not render image completely

Tags: image, ipad, uiwebview

I am experiencing a weird bug trying to display images in a UIWebView using an iPad4 and iPad3. The Background images behind the gray circle is rendered by the native part of the app, so please ignore that those images are rendered correctly. Most of the time the gray circle is rendered correctly like this [image: correct image]. Sometimes though it looks like this [image: broken image].

I tested it several times on an iPad2, 3 and 4. The error only occurs on the retina iPads (3 and 4). They both use a retina image which is bigger than the image used on the iPad2 (1.2MB to 400KB). As this error does not occur with the any other smaller images in the app, I assume that I am reaching some kind of size limit for rendering. I am confused however that the error only happens is in 1 of 4 tries.

I tried the hardware acceleration trick of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501980/ios-safari-image-rendering-issue) with no luck. I also read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046143/really-long-background-image-does-not-render-on-ipad-safari) about images having too many pixels but that does not seem to be the case as my retina image just has round about 1MP. Has anyone experienced a similar behavior or even a solution? Thx a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the image with another identical in pixel numbers but smaller (300KB) and it seems to be displayed correctly all the time. I put this as an "answer" for other users with the same problem. But of course there may be better ways that actually solve the problem.