# iOS html app : big scrolling list causes elements to disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css, html

I'm making a Facebook friends picker, with items that contain an avatar and the user's name. While scrolling quickly, elements often appear with a delay.

I realise that my question is similar to this one : [iPad Safari scrolling causes HTML elements to disappear and reappear with a delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807620/ipad-safari-scrolling-causes-html-elements-to-disappear-and-reappear-with-a-dela)
However, the accepted answer doesn't solve my problem, as it causes my app to crash after scrolling for a while. The scrolling also becomes a lot more laggy.

I don't know the details of how GPU rendering works, but my guess is that each row becomes a texture in the GPU, and after a while it's just too much.

Anything else I can try? There's no relative positioning going on btw.
I have about 700 friends, but I can only imagine the problem getting worse as the list becomes longer, because when I deliberately set it to show less items, the problem seems to goe away.

Thanks!

Comment: If anyone knows of a way to (slightly) limit the speed of the momentum scrolling, that would probably help a great deal.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using the [ng-grid](http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/) function in [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/) for long lists that need scrolling in HTML apps. Other suggestions would be just to optimise the CSS and make sure there aren't alot of box-shadows, gradients etc that take up alot of processing power when scrolling.

Hope that helps and any questions just let me know!

Comment: I tried removing all styles from my items, and while it improved the problem slightly, it was still there. But I'll give ng-grid a try, thanks!

Comment: No worries! If I've helped, accepting as answer would be great :)

Comment: Off course :) Need to finish some other work first though. Do you happen to know if this component works well with webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch?

Comment: I just downloaded ng-grid, and tested the workbench/index3.html demo on my iphone (as that was the only one with a relatively big data set), and it was very laggy, so this doesn't look too promising.

Answer (score 0):

Does this solve your problem?

```css
overflow-y: auto;
```

Add that to the your container.

(Presumably just `overflow: auto;` would work too depending on your needs.)