# How to enable a sticky menu within the Ionic framework?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a view where I need to implement a sticky menu inside of the **[Ionic framework](http://ionic.io/)**.

Looking for an Angular not jQuery solution I found **[ngSticky](https://github.com/d-oliveros/ngSticky)**. Great library works perfect, the problem however is that it won't work inside of the Ionic directive `<ion-content>`.

I asked a [previous question about it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32237459/ngsticky-plugin-not-working-when-the-sticky-directive-is-used-inside-of-a-templa/32242546#32242546), and then figured out what was going on:

---

Because the parent container that `ion-content` creates has the following style on it:

```
<div class="scroll" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) scale(1);">
```

It's a fix for an [iPad scrolling bug as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807620/ipad-safari-scrolling-causes-html-elements-to-disappear-and-reappear-with-a-dela).

So I can't remove that style and removing it would involve making changes to the core `ionic.bundle.js` file anyways.

The only thing I can think of now at the moment, is to write some code to detect when the sticky header hits the top, then remove that block of HTML out of `ion-content` and replace it above the `ion-content` container.

**Is there any other way around this?**

Here is a Plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/DiVfOzjJevSFOtVitYty?p=preview
There is a jQuery hack in place that removes the style tag so you can see how it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know its not a good solution, but I'd simply go for applying CSS rule with !important to override the current style

```
.pane {
   transform: none !important;
   -webkit-transform: none; /* Safari and Chrome */
   -moz-transform: none; /* Firefox */
   -ms-transform: none; /* IE 9 */
   -o-transform: none; /* Opera */
}
```

[**Plunkr Here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/f11aGetOI6mjxJTxvRLc?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks, but yeah that won't be ideal... also inside my app, when I do that.. Ionic loses the scroll ability, which Plunkr does not lose. However I think I found the perfect solution here! http://market.ionic.io/plugins/ionic-scroll-sista

Comment: @LeonGaban That's cool.. you should go for it then..Cheers.. :)

Comment: This is still super frustrating, cannot get this library to work at all... may just have to resort to some unfortunate jQuery magic.

Comment: @LeonGaban don't think so..Wondering what logic will be there to do magic?

Comment: I literally would have to rip out my `<header id="social-media-header">` and place it out of the `<ion-content>` container... then change some css, I think I can get this done with just vanilla javascript though. Just frustrated that I tried 2 plugins specifically built for this exact problem, and both failed :(

Comment: Would you mind a look at this Plunkr? I recreated it with the correct use of `ion-content` as in my current app. The problem continues here: http://plnkr.co/edit/u7T5YES7NLKkLoqAPzm7?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to create something similar.

I had an image on top and a button below. As I'm scrolling down the page I wanted the button to stay on top.

*(sticky menu === sticky button === all the same)*

Code below isn't working reliably and is full of hacks so I'm hesitant to share it... In fact I've actually removed it from the codebase, posting here for **illustrational purposes** only:

```
  // INITIALISATION SETUP 
  var $button = $(".button-middle-wrapper");
  var buttonOffset;

  var _measureOffset = function() {
    buttonOffset = $button.offset().top;
  };

  setTimeout(_measureOffset, 500); // HACK: during initialisation image is not loaded - therefore image offset is not correct - wait for image to load?

  $(window).resize(_measureOffset);

  // METHOD AVAILABLE ON THE SCOPE
  $scope.fixButtonToTop = function() {
    var scrollPosition = $ionicScrollDelegate.getScrollPosition().top;

    if (scrollPosition > buttonOffset - 30) {
      $button.css({"top": scrollPosition + 30}); // normally it is enough to set position to "fixed" - in Ionic case we do not scroll browser window - we do tranlations and setting positions - so we manually calculate position
    } else {
      $button.css({"top": ""});
    }
  };
```

And then in the view: `<ion-content on-scroll="fixButtonToTop">`

---

Not only the code is terrible but I've also committed one of the common mistakes described here: https://www.toptal.com/ionic/most-common-ionic-development-mistakes

> Common Mistake #8: Binding Events to onscroll, and Forgetting About requestAnimationFrame