# DIV with absolute position disappear on scrolling on iPad and iPhone

Tags: css, scroll, mobile-safari, layer

I have a sidebar that contains some products filters on an ecommerce website and has an absolute position.
It works well on all browsers except for Safari on iPad and iPhone. It randomly disappear when the page scroll.

I have tried to use the -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); trick as reported in many articles and other "tricks", but nothing work for me

([iPad Safari scrolling causes HTML elements to disappear and reappear with a delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807620/ipad-safari-scrolling-causes-html-elements-to-disappear-and-reappear-with-a-dela))

You can see the page at http://www.hardlyeverwornit.com/alexander-mcqueen

The sidebar is visible on mobile and iPad by clicking the "REFINE SEARCH" button.
The class name is "new-search-results-filters". At the moment I have removed the "tranlate3d ..." because it wasn't working.

Comment: Seems like you want this to be position: fixed;

Comment: I have tried to use the fixed position but doesn't fix the issue. Also I have read that would be better to avoid the fixed position for Safari