# Scrolling really quickly on Firefox, iPad, and Safari causes elements to disappear then reappear

Tags: css, ipad, firefox, safari

I'm curious as to why this happens. It's most visible on Firefox, and on an iPad, but Safari also suffers from this a bit.

I've seen this in two spots.

I have a background picture, which is dark, and a white container on top of it which takes up 90% of the screen and contains all the content. On Firefox and on an iPad, If I scroll really quickly the white will disappear, then reappear.

I also have a navbar that once a user has scrolled 30 pixels from the top, it will add a class with a fixed position; it can't start out as fixed. On chrome it will work as expected, but on Firefox and Safari a delay will occur then the menu will be added.

The iPad seems to be due to this: [iPad Safari scrolling causes HTML elements to disappear and reappear with a delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807620/ipad-safari-scrolling-causes-html-elements-to-disappear-and-reappear-with-a-dela) (currently haven't tested)

The content disappearing only happens when I scroll really quickly, but the menu will occur at a just a regular scroll rate; if I scroll really slowly it will work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Element appearing to blank during scroll

This is because sometimes the browsers can't render fast enough to keep up with the scroll. Rather than cause a janky scroll, they just stop rending anything until they can catch up. This is particularly likely to happen on mobile where you scroll really fast with just a flick of the finger, but resources are pretty low.

---

#### Navbar scroll event delayed

This depends on the browser, but again they are trying to ensure a fast scroll experience. One of the things they might do is refuse to do expensive `onscroll` events until after the scroll is mostly over. I also believe that refusing to do `onscroll` events allows them to do cool hardware acceleration that is beyond my ability to answer.

---

[This](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/layers/) html5rocks article is an interesting starting point for reading about how browsers do hardware acceleration.