# Any ideas on rendering issues on mobile safari

Tags: css, vue.js, safari, mobile-safari

I'm having some weird rendering issues when using safari on ios for my web application. The strange thing is, that it mostly works as intended, but these bugs appear sometimes and there is no obvious pattern when this happens.

Correct Examples:

[image: correct 1]
[image: correct 2]

Buggy Examples:

[image: buggy 1]
[image: buggy 2]

Does someone have any slight idea, why this could happen, or could potentially cause this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by using this hack on some of the elements:

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0)
```

See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10170170/8494034